# Vaadin 23.2.7 button and menuBar have different sizes

Tags: button, vaadin, menuitem, menubar

I add to the HorizontalLayout with the same dimensions

button:

```
Icon icon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.SEARCH);
Button searchButton = new Button("Search", icon);
searchButton.setIconAfterText(false);
searchButton.setWidth(140, Unit.PIXELS);
searchButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

layout.add(searchButton);
```

and menuBar

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.setWidth(140, Unit.PIXELS);
menuBar.addThemeVariants(MenuBarVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
menuBar.addItem("Save");

layout.add(menuBar);
```

The display of elements in the browser is different, despite the same width (140, Unit.PIXELS).

[image]

Please tell me how it can be fixed

I tried different options here https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/components/menu-bar, but it didn't help

I tried https://start.vaadin.com/app create a new project (Vaadin 24) with the same code, but the result is equally bad :(

[image]

Comment: You should probably set the width to the Menu Bar item instead. Now you’re setting the width of the whole Menu Bar, but as it can contain multiple items/buttons, and collapse them to an overflow item if there’s not enough space, it doesn't distribute the left-over space to the items/buttons.

Comment: I've tried it. I created a Label with the same size and added it to MenuBar. It didn't help. I decided to abandon Button. I replaced all the Buttons with MenuBar. Now everything looks the same

Comment: I mean something like `var menuItem = menuBar.addItem("Save"); menuItem.setWidth("140px");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all the Buttons with MenuBar. Now everything looks the same

before:

```
Icon icon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.SEARCH);
Button searchButton = new Button("Search", icon);
searchButton.setIconAfterText(false);
searchButton.setWidth(140, Unit.PIXELS);
searchButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

layout.add(searchButton);

MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.setWidth(140, Unit.PIXELS);
menuBar.addThemeVariants(MenuBarVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
menuBar.addItem("Save");

layout.add(menuBar);
```

after:

```
            searchMenuBar = new MenuBar();
        searchMenuBar.setWidth(150, Unit.PIXELS);
        searchMenuBar.addThemeVariants(MenuBarVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        Label findLabel = new Label("Search");
        findLabel.setWidth(90, Unit.PIXELS);
        MenuItemUtil.createIconItem(searchMenuBar, VaadinIcon.SEARCH, findLabel, null);

layout.add(searchMenuBar);

        saveMenuBar = new MenuBar();
        saveMenuBar.setWidth(150, Unit.PIXELS);
        saveMenuBar.addThemeVariants(MenuBarVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        saveMenuBar.setEnabled(false);
        Label saveTitle = new Label("Save");
        saveTitle.setWidth(90, Unit.PIXELS);
        menuItem = MenuItemUtil.createIconItem(saveMenuBar, VaadinIcon.DOWNLOAD, saveTitle, null);
        SubMenu moveSubMenu = menuItem.getSubMenu();
        moveSubMenu.addItem("Save to PDF");


layout.add(saveMenuBar);
```